# Ciclo fordá resultados Nan! Como obter valores reais?

Tags: python, pandas

Uma das partes do meu script pretende determinar a área de um gráfico pela aproximação a trapézio. Dentro da classe criei a seguinte função que manipula o self.df, que se trata de uma DataFrame

```
def areas(self):
    area = 0.
    x = list(self.df['wavelenght'])
    y = list(self.df['R'])

    tamanho = len(self.df)

    for i in range(tamanho):
        if i == tamanho - 1:
            break

        x0 = x[i]
        y0 = y[i]

        x1 = y[i+1]
        y1 = y[i+1]

        h = x1 - x0
        B = y1 + y0

        area += (B/2.)*h
        print(area)
    return area
```

A linha que tem print(area) serve para seguir o valor de área em cada ciclo for. No texto de saída, depois de várias linhas com valores float chega uma altura em que isto ocorre

```
0.514712375
0.517317875
0.51993125
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
nan
```

Manualmente consigo obter os valores que estes nan deveriam obter mas pretendo manipular mais de 100 DataFrames.

Porque me está a dar estas saídas? Qual é a melhor solução?

Comment: `tamanho = len(self.df)` não seria `tamanho = len(self.df['R'])` ?

Comment: Ambos vao dar o mesmo valor, neste caso trata-se do número de linhas que o dataframe tem

Answer (score 0):

`nan`, significa: "Não é um número", isto é, um valor em ponto flutante que vc obtem quando executa um cálculo cujo resultado não pode ser expresso como um número, qualquer cálculo que vc executar com `nan`, resultará em `nan`. Sugiro que vc altere o `for`, acrescentado antes do `print(area)` o seguinte:

```
print('Valor de b: ', b)
print('valor de h:', h)
```

Então vá em um console python, pegue os valores de `b` e `h` (nas linhas onde os resultados tenham sido `nan`) e veja se não são `nan`:

```
import math
print (math.isnan(value))
```

Ou então acrescente essas linhas no proprio loop for.

Vc deve checar tb (na console, pq no loop está.) se a equação para gerar a nova area (`area += (B/2.)*h`), não está gerando um `nan`.

Se encontrar `nan` nessas variáveis, provavelmente tem algum erro ou no seu algoritmo ou nos dados do dataframe, cheque-os.